# MySQL - left join multiplication

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have problem with query mysql... 
The query multiplies the amount and should not

table "orders":

```
[ID, NAME      ]
[22 , "Example"]
```

table "payments":

```
[ID, ORDER_ID, AMOUNT]
[1 , 22      , 120   ]
```

table "documents":

```
[ID, ORDER_ID, NAME]
[1 , 22      , "Test 1"]
[2 , 22      , "Test 2"]
```

**I want to get:**

```
[ID, NAME     , PRICE_SUM, INDEXS          ]
[22, "Example", 120      , "Test 1, Test 2"]
```

**And now I'm getting it (error in PRICE_SUM)**

```
[ID, NAME     , PRICE_SUM, INDEXS          ]
[22, "Example", 240      , "Test 1, Test 2"]
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
    orders.id,
    orders.name, 
    sum(payments.amount) as price_sum, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CASE WHEN documents.name = "Private" THEN documents.index END
    ) AS indexs
FROM 
    `orders` 
    LEFT JOIN `payments` ON `payments`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `documents` ON `documents`.`id_order` = `orders`.`id` AND `documents`.`name` = "Private"
GROUP BY 
    `orders`.`id` 
ORDER BY 
    `orders`.`id` DESC
```

Comment: What is the issue with `price_sum` is it that `price_sum` should be 120?

Comment: Your query is invalid SQL anyway, because you are selecting columns (orders.name) that are not part of the GROUPing. MySQL tolerates this error under lax settings, but the value you get will be that of one _random_ record within the group.

Comment: @LewisBrowne becouse for order is 1 payments...

Comment: Besides that, the result is only natural, because your group contains _two_ records for order id 22. Both those records contain an amount of 120, and summing up two times 120 just results in 240, works as designed. If you do not want that, then you should not throw your multiple document records you have for an order into this mix in the first place.

Comment: But I need Indexs of documents for the order

Comment: Where do you get documents.index from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a correlated sub query in the select something like this:

```
SELECT 
    o.id,
    o.name, 
    sum(p.amount) as price_sum, 
    (select GROUP_CONCAT(
        d.name
        )
        from  d 
          where d.order_id = o.id

    ) AS indexs
FROM  o
LEFT JOIN  p ON p.`order_id` = o.`id` 
GROUP BY 
    o.`id`,o.name 
ORDER BY 
    o.`id` DESC
```

Given

```
drop table if exists o,p,d;
create table o (ID int, NAME varchar(20));
insert into o values
(22 , 'Example');

create table p (ID INT, ORDER_ID INT, AMOUNT INT);
INSERT INTO P VALUES
(1 , 22      , 120 );

CREATE TABLE D (ID INT, ORDER_ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO D VALUES
(1 , 22      , 'Test 1'),
(2 , 22      , 'Test 2');
```

The query results in

```
+------+---------+-----------+---------------+
| id   | name    | price_sum | indexs        |
+------+---------+-----------+---------------+
|   22 | Example |       120 | Test 1,Test 2 |
+------+---------+-----------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: And how would I want to use: where?

Comment: What where do you want - there isn't one in the question.

Comment: I know... So if i want find "index" that...?
Thanks!

Comment: This bit in your question did not make sense CASE WHEN documents.name = "Private" THEN documents.index END since there are no documents.name = "Private" or documents.index in the sample data and  I could not figure out what they were for.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Documents` table, you have `Order_Id` 22 twice - this will double the amount when you join `Documents` with `Payments`.